# "_KUTTypeMovie_" Referenced from: Error in xcode

Tags: iphone

Hey guys I'm trying to create an app in xcode that in long story short records video, and xcode is proclaiming the following: "*KUTTypeMovie* Referenced from:"

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Here is my code.

#import < MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>

@implementation OverlayViewController

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  OverlayView *overlay = [[OverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGTH)];

  // Create a new image picker instance:
  UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

  // Set the image picker source:
  picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
  picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];

Comment: see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766860/save-videos-in-iphone-simulator-upload-it-to-the-web-services/8740706#8740706

Answer (score 1):

Add the MobileCoreServices.framework to your target

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the MobileCoreServices.framework to your target then add the following:

```
 #import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
```