# save videos in iphone simulator & upload it to the web services

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator

I just want to know that how I can save the videos to the iphone simulator & how I can upload it to the web services?

Thanks.

---

```
vpc=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    vpc.delegate=self;
    vpc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    vpc.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:vpc.sourceType];
    vpc.allowsEditing = NO;
    vpc.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
    [self presentModalViewController:vpc animated:YES];
```

i am doing this it gives an error, kuTType undeclared before it used, i dont know about the kuTTypeMovies, please reply as soon as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing one of below framework

```
libz.1.2.3.dylib
MobileCoreServices.framwork
SystemConfiguration.framwork
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to  import framework **#import MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h**

If u got an error when u import framework.try below method I found.

**1)** open your project profile

**2)** build phases > link binary with libraries

**3)** click **+** , add **MobileCoreService framework**

4) now see it in left side.In the **Headers folder of framework**.find file name **MobileCoreServices.h**

5) Now open **.h** file, simple **drag it below #import UIKit/UIKit.h**

Note : make sure you need to drag it into **#import<....>**

Now what...? Thats it.You can see **KuTTYpeMovie in .m file**...thanks